# Find JSON in plain text

Tags: php, json, regex

I am struggling with something I could not solve yet.

A third-party-app generates a JSON, which I want to work with.

But unfortunately it prefixes the output with:

```
Google Chrome 1.2.3.4 
Mozilla Firefox 73.0
[2020-08-31 14:35:50] INFO: Running tests
{
... complex json object
}
```

Now I wonder how I could safely search for the JSON object in this output. Any ideas here?

Comment: Strip everything before the first `{`?

Comment: Try to find some pattern. It's always the third line? The first `{` starts the json?

Comment: Yes, it's always the third line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions approach as:

```
<?php
$input = 'Google Chrome 1.2.3.4 
Mozilla Firefox 73.0
[2020-08-31 14:35:50] INFO: Running tests
{
    "complex": "json object",
    "somekey1": {"somekey2":33},
    "somekey3": [36,56]
}';

preg_match('/({.*})/mis', $input, $matches);
var_dump(json_decode($matches[0]));
```

See working example here: [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=4f14f24c6fd575f05cbaf5938faaf2a1&sqlses=null&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql57)